# Make Wildfly decode URL Path Parameters

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly

How to make Wildfly to decode URL Path Parameters automatically when a request is received?
E.g.,
Request URI

```
/user/dusayanta%23XYZ
```

Should result into

```
/user/dusayanta#XYZ
```

Comment: Use `@PathParam`. The value is URL decoded unless this is disabled using the `@Encoded` annotation.

Comment: Thank You so much @JasperdeVries, your suggestion works. you can post it as an answer.

Comment: I had ```@Encoded``` at class scope, i commented it out and things started working as per expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `@PathParam`. The value is URL decoded unless this is disabled using the `@Encoded` annotation.

See also:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html